# Filtering questions not being voted on by myself?

Tags: support

Is there a search-query that gives me a list of all questions which haven't been voted on **by myself** so far?

(In case you wonder: This could be useful if you want to go systematically through questions you haven't seen/voted-on yet while avoiding going through ALL questions.)

Comment: [feature-request]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's any way to do that using the search.  I thought I'd try writing a query on http://data.stackexchange.com to retrieve the info, but it turns out that "who voted for a given question" is not publicly-accessible data.

So it looks like short of having this implemented by a Stack Exchange developer and added to the existing search functionality, it simply won't happen.